# Selenium xpath all (//*) doesn't take every css elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to list every color on different websites using selenium (XPath) and I don't know why my script doesn't get them all.

```
background_ele = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@style,'background')]")
colors_ele = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@style,'color')]")
background_colors = [x.value_of_css_property('background-color') for x in background_ele]
colors = [x.value_of_css_property('background-color') for x in colors_ele]
```

This code should get every element that has a background or a color attribute but when I run it for this website: "www.example.com" I don't see the color below which appears on the footer and the header:

```
background-color: rgb(54, 64, 66) !important;
```

I only print those ones:

```
['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(169, 68, 66, 1)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)']
```

Is there an issue with my code or maybe a more efficient way to do this using selenium?

**UPDATES**

My script actually only takes the  tags in the html and not in the css files.

```
<div class="example"style="src="https://example.com/img/slider.jpg"></div>
```

How can I use selenium to target every css attribute (from the css files) that contains the parameter "background" or "color"?

Comment: It looks like some of the `styles` are defined in separated style text/css blocks. Try to get those and look for `backgroundColor`s.

Comment: @wp78de how can I find those with selenium? Shouldn't it catch them automatically?

Comment: @jjyoh Do you want to get all the effective-computed colors?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not process CSS-properties that are missing in the DOM-structure. Alternatively, you can use [jQuery.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) by applying a class for each needed node what allows to find an element in a standard way:
for my example below is `//div[contains(@class, 'found')]`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("*").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(54, 64, 66)";
 }).text("true").addClass("found"); 
});
```

```css
.white {
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.black {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.carmine {
background-color: rgba(169, 68, 66, 1);
}
.cosmos {
background-color: rgb(54, 64, 66);
}
.found {
color: green !important;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="white">false</div>
<div class="black">false</div>
<div class="carmine">false</div>
<div class="cosmos">false</div>
```